# What is 'jQuery' keyword?

Tags: jquery

I understand $ keyword resolves to jQuery.

So `$(document).ready(function(){});`
resolves to `jQuery(document).ready(function(){});`

However what is jQuery keyword in itself? I have browsed through various articles but i havent found any meaningful answer.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library. See http://jquery.com/ for all sorts of information.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't a keyword. It is, like `$`, an *identifier*. In this context it represents a variable. When you add jQuery to a page it creates the `jQuery` and `$` variables, both of which point to the same object.

Other than being clearer and less likely to conflict with variables created by other libraries, there are no differences between the `jQuery` and `$` variables.

Comment: Identifier is an excellent way of describing it. In my own answer I struggled to think of a good word to describe it (and "variable", though accurate, sounded too cheesy).

Comment: not to be confused with `var $variableName` which is just notation used to signify that `$variableName` holds a jQuery object i.e. `$variableName = $("#SomeHTMLTagID")`

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a JavaScript library. The syntax `$` or `jQuery` refers to the the library's hook that allows for you to use its built in for using the library's functions.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is open source, cross-browser JavaScript library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML. jQuery's  syntax is designed to make it easier to navigate a document, select DOM elements, create animations, handle events, and develop Ajax applications.

$ sign is just an alias for jQuery, a short version of jQuery. The idea is that everything is done with this one global symbol.